# Make Journey Builder Decision Split Based on Sync'd DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

Basic points:
• My Journey Has Entry Source from Salesforce Data so the DE is auto-generated.
• I created a synced DE from the custom object in SFDC so that after a few days I can check on a field from that object to determine if I want to send a re-mail or not
• I can't connect the auto-create DE in Contact Builder to the sync'd DE because there are no field lengths and SFMC wont let me add field lengths.

How do I allow the journey to see SFDC field updates.

More Detail:
We have a program we are inviting people to enroll in and a custom object for this program with a custom field called 'Status'
The Journey Entry criteria says to inject the contact when the Status = Invited
At some point, there is a community page that handles enrollment; when the customer enrolls, the Status field changes to 'Enrolled'.

After 5 days, I want to check if Status = 'Enrolled' or not and if so, they can exit the journey but if not, send a re-invite email.

My problem is that I can't make the Journey re-call salesforce for the decision split, but I thought for sure the journey could look at a sync'd DE for a decision split.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best practice is never to work directly with Synced DEs, but query these into either a 1:1 copy or, even better, build a custom DE specifically for the purpose. This new DE should then be connected in an Attribute Group of Data Designer, in Contact Builder - allowing you to select its fields under Contact Data in the decision split of your Journey.

I know this will introduce a delay, since you are depending on your automations running, but then, you can build an automation with multiple instances of the same query, with wait steps in between. I.e. Query - 10m wait - Query - 10m wait - and so on, until you get an execution time of approx 50 minutes. Then you reduce the delay to 10 minutes instead of an hour.

Comment: Thats a great idea.  I'll try it out and see how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: Wow @Lukas Lunow, you just solved a problem i had with interval times in JB. I'm curious though, will running that query every ten minutes cause any performance issues?

Comment: @garek007 depends on the running time of individual queries. Make sure they finish well before the automation starts again. Another way of solving it is by duplicating entire automation, and scheduling the duplicates to run 10 minutes apart. Here you will have better control with the solution.

Comment: Honestly I could do it every 15 minutes and it would probably be fine

Comment: Any luck, @JulieHurtz ?

Comment: I created an automation that brought the sync'd DE data into the a new DE and added a 30 minute wait time (that was as often as I needed it) and have the automation running every hour.  Then, used contact builder to link that new DE to the contact key so JB can see the updated data.  Thanks Lukas.